# Error: expected declaration before “}” token

Tags: arduino

The error it shows says:

```
5:1: error: expected declaration before “}” token.
```

I'm trying that with a ultrasonic sensor, depending on the distance of an object occurs something with LEDs:

- If the distance is lower than 10 then 2 LEDs go on and 1 off.
- If the distance is between 10 and 50, 2 of the LEDs will blink and the other will be off.
- If the distance is higher than 50 then only the green LED will be on.

This is my code:

```cpp
long d; 
long t;
}

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, INPUT);
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
    //first pulse:
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    t=pulseIn(8, HIGH);
    //we calculate d:
    d= int(0.017*t);
    Serial.println(d);
    Serial.println(" cm");
    delay(1000);
} 

if (d<10) { //if d is smaller than 10 then
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);//LED red on
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);//LED red on
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);//LED green off
}
else if (d>10 && d<50) {//if d is higher than 10 and smaller than 50 then
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);//LED red on
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);//LED red on
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);//LED green off
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);//LED red off
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);//LED red off
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);//LED green off
    delay(500);//this will make the red LEDs blink
}
else (d>50) {//if d is higher than 50 then
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);//LED red off
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);//LED red off
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);//LED green on
}
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT:

So I changed the code as you said and there are now more errors:

```cpp
long d; 
long t;

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, INPUT);
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
    //first pulse:
    digitalWrite(9,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    t=pulseIn(8, HIGH);
    //we calculate d:
    d= int(0.017*t);
    Serial.println(d);
    Serial.println(" cm");
    delay(1000);
} 

if (d<10) { //if d is smaller than 10 then
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);//LED red on
    digitalWrite(11,HIGH);//LED red on
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);//LED green off
}
else if (d>10 && d<50) {//if d is higher than 10 and smaller than 50 then
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);//LED red on
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);//LED red on
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);//LED green off
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);//LED red off
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);//LED red off
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);//LED green off
    delay(500);//this will make the red LEDs blink
}
else if (d>50) {//if d is higher than 50 then
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);//LED red off
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);//LED red off
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);//LED green on
}
```

The actual errors are:

```
27:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
32:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
42:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
Exit status 1
```

Comment: Well, which line of code is the error message referring to? And why is there a `}` on the line before `void setup() {`?

Comment: Also, `else (d>50) {` looks strange. Did you mean `else if (d>50) {`?

Comment: Mismatched braces are a typographical error, not suitable for asking a question on Stack Overflow. Also, for future reference: when posting a question to Stack Overflow, the title should state a summary of the question and/or the context of the question itself, not your status as a programmer.

Comment: @Michael it refers to line 5 thank you for answering!

Comment: Use ctrl+t for auto format, and whenever if or else is on the left without any spaces, it's outside of function... Also what should happened if d is 10 or 50? You are covering everithing but those two values... Maybe you should take a look at some tutorial about C++

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted your code:

- In the first example there is an extra `}` on the third line and on the last line.
- In both examples the if-else structure is outside the `loop()` or any other function, which gives you the errors.